# Repeater ItemCommand Doesnt fire

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemcommand

I have tried post on same subject but didn't work. it didn't actually fire event

> What I want

I want to fire 
`ItemCommand` event when some one click on repeater.

> Issue

The `ItemCommand` is not fired.

```
EnableViewState=true
```

Here is by code:

Html:

```
<table>
              <asp:Repeater ID="outerRepeater" runat="server"
                    OnItemDataBound="outer_OnitemdataBound" 
                  onitemcommand="outerRepeater_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Rgallery" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 0 ? "<tr>" : string.Empty %>  
                        <td>
                            <img src="<%# Eval("ImgPath") %>" style="height:300px; width:300px;" alt="" />
                                <div class="caption">
                         <h3><%# Eval("Type") %></h3>
                         <p><b><%# Eval("SubType") %></b></p>
                         <p{font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; font-size: 25px}>Price:<i class="fa fa-inr fa-fw"><%# Eval("Price") %></i></p>
                         <p><asp:Button ID="btnBuy" CommandName="Buy" CommandArgument="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %>' runat="server" />
                         </p>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 3 ? "</tr>" : string.Empty%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
              <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </table>
```

and here is code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
        dummy.Columns.Add();
        dummy.Rows.Add();
        rptMain.DataSource = dummy;
        rptMain.DataBind();
        outerRepeater.DataSource = dummy;
        outerRepeater.DataBind();
    }
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    { return; }

}

protected void outerRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Here is a code I want to fire
}
protected void outer_OnitemdataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater repeater = e.Item.FindControl("RGallery") as Repeater;
    repeater.DataSource = db.GetTable("SELECT `Did`, `Type`, `SubType`, `Gender`, `Price`, `ImgPath` FROM `designs` ORDER BY `Did` DESC");
    repeater.DataBind();
}
```

> What i have tried so far

**Method 1**

I have put `onItemCommand="rptthumbnail_ItemCommand"` But i didn't worked.

Method 2 
I have add handlar in `OnInit()` But i didn't worked too.

Can some please identify that what's the problem
 Please help me with this.....

Comment: I hope you want to trigger the `ItemCommand` event of outer repeater control when button `btnBuy` is clicked? But this button is present inside nested repeater so the `itemCommand` event of that repeater will be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your button is the child of your inner repeater, it will trigger the `ItemCommand` event on that instead. Moving the event binding down to that repeater should fix it for you.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="outerRepeater" runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="outer_OnitemdataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Rgallery" runat="server"
            OnItemCommand="Rgallery_ItemCommand">
```

```
protected void Rgallery_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Here is a code I want to fire
}
```